# Solutions missing from $(0^\circ,180^\circ)$ for $2 \tan 3x+5 \sin 3x=0$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $2 \tan 3x+5 \sin 3x=0$ for $x\in(0^\circ,180^\circ).$

By getting to $\cos 3x=-0.4,$ I got some but not all of the required answers: $38^\circ, 82^\circ \text { and } 157^\circ,$ but not $0^\circ, 60^\circ, 120^\circ, 180^\circ.$ How do I get the remaining solutions?

Comment: You seem to have cancelled $\sin (3x)$. You have to include roots of $\sin (3x)=0$ also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Rewrite the above as $2 \ \frac {\sin 3x}{\cos 3x} + 5 \sin 3x = 0$ and factor out $\sin 3x$.  Then, realize you have $\sin 3x (\frac {2}{\cos 3x}+5) = 0$ and you will have two equations to consider.

Answer (score 3):

You are making the same rookie mistake as here: $$5x+x=0\\5+1=0\\6=0.$$ The error is in the first line: dividing an equation by an expression ($x$ or $\sin(3x)$ or etc.) that isn't universally nonzero. (In contrast, it is absolutely valid to divide an equation by, for example, $\sec x,$ which never equals zero.)

> By getting to $\cos 3x=-0.4,$ I got some but not all of the required answers

To correct your work, just append ‘or $\sin(3x)=0$’ to your first step, like so:

$$2 \tan 3x+5 \sin 3x=0\\\cos 3x=-0.4\quad\color\red{\text{or}\quad\sin(3x)=0}.$$ This captures all the solutions, for both these cases:
  (**I**) $\sin(3x)$ is nonzero, 
  (**II**) $\sin(3x)$ is zero.

Similarly, this is correct: $$5x+x=0\\5+1=0\quad\color\red{\text{or}\quad x=0}\\x=0.$$